# Stop two inputs being split onto different lines when it's not needed

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap for a website, and this one part is bugging me. When it hits a certain length, it'll start resizing the inputs, though with date and time, it'll also put them onto new lines which is not needed.

It looks nice if both of them together are stretched out the same space as the rest of the input boxes, but they don't need to be so wide, so I want it to stay on the same line (at the same size ratio) until a much smaller width is given.

Here is the trimmed down version of the code I have:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-8">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input name="date" type="text" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" class="form-control">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input name="time" type="time" placeholder="hh:mm" class="form-control">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tX3ae/653/

When width is big enough:
[image]

When it's too small:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want they to stay even in mobile to large dekstop

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-8">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input name="date" type="text" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" class="form-control">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-4">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input name="time" type="time" placeholder="hh:mm" class="form-control">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Actually, you can configure for each screen size using `xs` for phone, `sm` for tablet, `md` for dekstop, and `lg` for larger dekstop.

Read it here : http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_system.asp

Comment: Thanks, I've got to head out in a minute but I'll ask here since you added the extra information, would you happen to know how I could revert back to separate lines if it hits a small enough width? `xs` works great, but not surprisingly it gets to point where it doesn't show the field properly :P

Comment: Well, as i describe, without some minor changes, for now you can only change it depend on the screen type (phone, tablet, etc). So if you want it to stay at tablet but split at mobile (so that it still look nice). Then use `col-sm-#`. It will change to split when bootstrap detect mobile. Is that what you mean?

Comment: And if you willing to customize bootstrap, i mean `col-sm-#` to have a smaller break point (smaller then the default one, which is the field still look nice and `properly` `:p`).  You can edit it here https://getbootstrap.com/customize/ on media query break point

Comment: Not sure if I posted a comment and it was removed or if it didn't end up posting, but I realised it was the break point I was after, but as I still want to use a CDN, I don't want to recreate the entire file. Here's the extra css needed to add an extra breaking point, it appears to work :)   - https://gist.github.com/firepol/7942411

Answer (score 2):

You should define your columns with "xs" size, like this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-8 col-xs-8">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input name="date" type="text" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" class="form-control">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
        <div class="form-group">
        <input name="time" type="time" placeholder="hh:mm" class="form-control">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is related to Bootstraps [grid layout](https://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid). As long as you do not specify rules for a smaller column range than you've set up, Bootstrap will consider using it's usual styling which handles a vertical layout for forms. So that being said, if you also specify a `col-xs-*` rule, you will be able to get what you want on even smaller screen sizes. If not, as I said, Bootstrap will '**normalize**' that for smaller sizes.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-8">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <input name="date" type="text" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" class="form-control">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-4">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <input name="time" type="time" placeholder="hh:mm" class="form-control">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

If you want the same column structure in all devices starting from the extra small you should use col-xs-* prefix, check out this page for better understanding of Bootstrap grid system - http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/twitter-bootstrap-tutorial/bootstrap-grid-system.php